# Angular js + Rails good idea?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, web, frontend

I have been using rails as backend and some basic css, js for frontend. I am the only one in dev now, but I thought it's better to separate frontend/backend for later when someone else joins as frontend. I was googling for a bit and figured angularjs might be a good combination.

However, I don't quite get other benefits of this combination(rails + angular) other than making separating front-end jobs. What are the other benefits of having angular in rails framework or any cons?

Thanks a lot!

======== EDIT ==============

Sorry that my question was too broad in some way.

In short, I was wondering if there are any reason why angular is such popular combination with rails. Compared to just using rails for everything(front+back), what are some benefits of using angular on the front end + rails backend-api? (speed, simplicity, DRY-er code......etc?).

I just started googling angular for several days now, and before actually getting into it, I wanted to hear from people having experience in it. Thank you.

Comment: I am thinking of SPA. rails api + angular receiving in the frontend

Comment: This question is too broad and is a poor fit for this format sohyeonlee.

Comment: Sorry that question is too broad. I agree to that. Maybe because I wanted a general pros/cons of using angular with rails. I will edit the question a bit. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Angular + Ruby on Rails is a very popular combination. Use rails for api endpoints and angular to retrieve and display data. You can also do most pages with rails and only some components with angular depending on how complex your pages need to be.

Comment: hello penner, thank you for your answer. So when using rails api + angular frontend, what are the benefits compared to just using rails for everything?

Comment: @sohyeonlee general differences between an SPA ans a traditional server-rendered website. Nothing particularly special.